# CakePHP Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created. core.php and bootstrap.php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have looked for answers before I posted this question, and it seems like the problem is in core.php or bootstrap.php file. I've seen someone said that I need to change prefixes or something like that, but I don't understand what exactly I should change them to. Can someone help me please? Here is the error page:

Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

```
Stack Trace
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 260 → Mysql->connect()
CORE/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php line 105 → DboSource->__construct(array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 3476 → ConnectionManager::getDataSource(string)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 1126 → Model->setDataSource(string)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 3498 → Model->setSource(string)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 1355 → Model->getDataSource()
CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php line 207 → Model->schema()
CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php line 459 → FormHelper->_introspectModel(string, string)
APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp line 85 → FormHelper->create(string, array)
CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 935 → include(string)
CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 897 → View->_evaluate(string, array)
CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 529 → View->_render(string)
CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 474 → View->renderLayout(string, string)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 952 → View->render(string, null)
APP/Controller/PagesController.php line 69 → Controller->render(string)
[internal function] → PagesController->display(string)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(PagesController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 185 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 160 → Dispatcher->_invoke(PagesController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Comment: Does this error occur on every page of your website or just the form you are working on? Does going to this page consistently cause this error? Did this error just _appear_ - i.e., what did you change before this error?

Comment: Well, this site worked perfectly on my local machine, but this started to happen when I uploaded it to live server. So this is just supposed to be index page. But Yes i just tried other pages same error. Here is the similar question, and I am pretty sure it is the right issue and answer, but that guy did not explain in details what I need to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004740/dispatcher-calls-code-from-another-app-occasionally

Comment: Overall, I think it is a caching problem... but have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: If it is really a caching problem, how about simply emptying the cache in app/tmp/cache? Cache field should *not* be committed and uploaded.

Comment: But there are 3 folders... models, view and persistent... don't I need them?

Comment: Ok, I did it, still same error page...

Answer (score 0):

Have you the proper connection between the site and the database? The only reason I can think of for this issue. Check you're configuration settings in the database.php file